# Is there a save_post hook for custom post types?

Tags: hooks

Is there a `save_post` hook for custom post types?

Example: `save_my_post_type`

I know there is `publish_my_post_type` but I'm looking for a save hook.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

the hook  is the same `save_post` just make sure its your post type ex:

```
add_action('save_post','save_post_callback');
function save_post_callback($post_id){
    global $post; 
    if ($post->post_type != 'MY_CUSTOM_POST_TYPE_NAME'){
        return;
    }
    //if you get here then it's your post type so do your thing....
}
```

Answer (score 113):

New solution, as of WP 3.7: `save_post_{$post_type}`

```
add_action( 'save_post_my_post_type', 'wpse63478_save' );
function wpse63478_save() {
    //save stuff
}
```

See the note on the [codex page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post_post-post_type/)

Comment: the new docs for this can be found here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post_post-post_type/

Answer (score 0):

call function my_func() whene publish(save) special post type

```php
add_action('save_post_[name_of_post_type]', ' my_func');
```

call function my_func() whene publish(save) all post type (post, page, product, ...)

```php
add_action('save_post', 'my_func');
```

Comment: can you expand this to provide more context? What is `course_metabox_save_value` and what did you mean by special metabox? The answers a bit concise/terse

Comment: [course]_metabox_save_value, course is a post type, If you write the name of the post type, the function will be called only when an post of the same post type is being saved

Comment: ex: add_action('save_post_product', 'course_metabox_save_value'), call function course_metabox_save_value(); whene product post type in woocommerce save or publish